# Register Dependencies in another Project

Tags: servicestack, autofac

My Models and DataContext are in another project to my Web MVC project in my solution. When I try to register my DataContext inside `AppHost` `Configure` method my DataContext is still `null` when I try to use it in a Repository, which my Service will use.

This is in `Configure`:

```
container.Register<WarrantyContext>(c => new WarrantyContext());
```

Then when I try to use the dependency in a Repository, like so:

```
public WarrantyContext _db { get; set; }
```

It is still `null`. Is there anything you have to do when trying to register a dependency from another project?

Comment: There is no special need when you are using multiple projects. However if you want to use property injection you need to register your repository like this: `container.Register<YourRepo>().As<IRepoInterface>().PropertiesAutowired()` or use constructor injection instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to look into...

- If you are using autofac make sure you have followed all the steps listed [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#use-autofac)
- Also it sounds like you have a Repository class that has the WarrantyContext as a property. There is a note [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#register-instances) that states *"When using the methods above, the properties and the constructor of the registered type aren't auto-wired (ie the properties and the constructor are not injected). You would need to do that manually like that"*. So if you have a class Repository (with a WarrantyContext property) being injected into your Service (like below) WarrantyContext will be null unless you manually register it.

  ```
  //To inject WarrantyContext into a Repository that is injected to Service 
  container.Register<Repository>(c => new Repository() { _db = c.Resolve<WarrantyContext>() });


  public class Repository 
  {
      public WarrantyContext _db { get; set; }
  }


  public class AService : Service
  {
      public Repository repo { get; set; }

      public object Any(ARequest request)
      {
          //CODE
      }
  }
  ```